# prepend 'member' to a domain name

Tags: domain-registration

If I register a domain (xyz.com), how is it handled if I would like a members portion of the site to be referenced at members.xyz.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most hosts and registrars allow you to manage your DNS for your domain. Here you should be able to set up sub-domains like members.example.com.

Comment: by virtue of you having answered the question (just barely) first, you get the checkmark.  Thank you

Answer (score 2):

"Members" would be a host in your domain, xyz.com.  So in DNS you would create an "A" (or host) record for "members".